# Cheese that Pairs with Spicy Food

Tags: pairing

I regularly make spicy Indian meals, but have been unable to find a cheese that pairs well.  Does anyone know of one?

Comment: There's tons of spicy Mexican food with cheese in it. That all tastes pretty good to me, so I suspect you need to define your question a little better.

Comment: Strange. I haven't found a cheese which *doesn't* pair well with spicy food.

Comment: I've added that it need be Indian food.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 So you're asking about pairings with dishes containing a huge variety of spices and other ingredients? And you're wanting cheese to eat alongside the dishes?

Comment: @Jefromi: Yes, mainly cayenne, cumin, and some paprika.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Homemade paneer, made with full-fat milk. Full-fat is important, as fat shields the capsaicin receptors in your tongue, and can make spicy food more palatable for those that can't handle spice.

You can buy paneer at an Indian market, but you can make it at home with minimal effort. All you need is a gallon of whole milk, some lemon juice, a pot to boil it in, and cheesecloth. [Here's a step-by-step guide with pictures](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Paneer-%28Indian-Cheese%29).

Answer (score 5):

Paneer is the obvious one. It can be used as a primary ingredient in a curry.